# Supabase Redirect URL not working for Deeplinking

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking, supabase, supabase-database

I am using Supabase for Auth with React Native and using React Navigation. When the user requests for password reset I set a redirect URL `myApp://updatepassword`. This link comes back with the link in the email but only always opens the initialRoute/first route on the navigation stack. I am using React Navigation. Note: `myApp://updatepassword` works as expected when I run it in the browser on the device or simulator. Is it possible Supabase only takes the first part of my route? That is `myApp://`?

I tried to set the redirect directly on the Supabase console as well as in the callback directly. I always get the right link (`https://...supabase.co/auth/v1/verify?token=&type=recovery&redirect_to=myApp://updatepassword/`) but still matches only the initial or first route on the stack. I saw an issue that says it needs the trailing slash but still doesn't work. Any ideas why would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I recommend watching [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5S4mPUpp4OvEgxBhoVxXb5YS1ZAZih2l) to see how the DevRel team implement such features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anybody runs into something similar. Turns out it's as a result of the # URL fragment in Supabase and React Navigation does not work with #. Using the `getStateFromPath` we can get the URL and replace # to access the URL properly with React Navigation. Like so:

```
import { getStateFromPath } from '@react-navigation/native';

const linking: LinkingOptions<RootStackParamList> = {
  prefixes: [prefix],
  config: {
    screens: {
      updatepassword: 'updatepassword'
    }
  },
  getStateFromPath: (path, options) => {
    const accessiblePath = path.replace("#", "?");

    return getStateFromPath(accessiblePath, options);
  },
};
```

This was answered here by @suchardao https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussion/10754#discussioncomment-4401396.

Comment: Hi can you tell how did you solve this? `myapp://updatapassword/#access_token=e&expires_at=1695801919&expires_in=86400&refresh_token=I&token_type=bearer&type=signup` I want to redirect to this link I have used your code but still didn't work for me. @Cortehz

Comment: Here is the question I have posted on StackOverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77197649/react-navigation-deep-link-not-navigate